# error 'import string_types ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package'

Tags: python-2.7, importerror

Using cmd on windows 10 to run Python 2.7.16. When I run a `.py` file which imports `scipy.py` it comes up with the error:

> "File "C:\Python27\scipy.py", line 18, in 
>       from .python import string_types
>   ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package"

As string_types should already be included in python, I don't understand why this error is happening and cant seem to get passed it. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: post your code it seems error with your import not with package

Comment: Python code:
import os
import sys
import six
import numpy as np
import sctools as sct 
import scipy
import scipy.io

Files:
In C:\python27
    python.py (and all standard python files and folders from installation)
    scipy.py
    sctools.py
    __init__.py

Answer (score 0):

you tried,

```
>>> from . import MyModule #MyModule.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
>>>
```

here `.` mean your current path

try,
    from MyModule import *

now you can use `string_types`

or

```
import MyModule as m
m.string_types
```

Comment: How can i do that if the scipy.py file is a compressed file? for example the first few lines are: 03f3 0d0a 497f e25c 6300 0000 0000 0000
0005 0000 0040 4000 0073 c700 0000 6400
0064 0100 6c00 006d 0100 5a01 0001 6400